# Why HCP portal service change file locations?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I am using HCP portal service to provide fiori launchpad, but I could not find my `controller` and `view` file in Chrome Network Tab.

And I also find that my image location is not working in Cloud.

I tried these two :

> ```
>                  var normalBusIcon = {
>                       url: '../images/1bus_normal.png',
>                       origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
>                       anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
>                   };
>                   
>                   var normalBusHoverIcon = {
>                       url: '/webapp/images/1bus_alert.png',
>                   };
> ```

The error is

> GET https://flpportal-iXXXXXXtrial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/images/1bus_normal.png 404 (Not Found)
>
> https://flpportal-iXXXXXXtrial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/webapp/images/1bus_alert.png 404 (Not Found)

File hiberarchy is

Projectname

|--webapp

--|--controller

--|--images

I want to know how portal service change the file location , how to use namespace in image url. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to images in your application, you should always use the `getModulePath` to assemble the URL. This would make sure your application not only works stand-alone, but also from a portal such as the portal service of the Fiori launchpad:

```
var normalBusIcon = {
    url: jQuery.sap.getModulePath("your.component.namespace") +
         "/images/1bus_normal.png",
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
};
```